# Deleting the commit history using git-filter-repo still shows the commit in closed PRs history

Tags: git, github, git-filter-repo

A checked-in secret was removed using `git-filter-repo` using the documentation here (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository). Although the commit no longer shows up, neither in the master nor in the feature branch, it still shows up in the closed PR's history.

Is there any way to remove it from there as well?

Comment: You can delete the PR, can't you?

Comment: github keeps references to merge requests head commits, run `git ls-remote origin` to view that. I have never tried to use git to delete such a reference, perhaps you could try to delete references linked to the targetted merge request.

Comment: @TimRoberts PRs can only be closed, but unlike issues, they can't be deleted, not even for admins or org owners, AFAIK.

Comment: something like `git push origin -d refs/pull/1234/head refs/pull/1234/merge`

Comment: or ask support about how to get rid of problematic pull requests

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, GitHub, like other Git hosts, doesn't garbage collect *any* orphaned commits, so if you know the full SHA of old commits you can still find them. The details of your question are actually covered by the Warning in the [article you linked](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) to:

> Warning: This article tells you how to make commits with sensitive data unreachable from any branches or tags in your repository on GitHub.com. However, **those commits may still be accessible** in any clones or forks of your repository, directly via their SHA-1 hashes in cached views on GitHub, and **through any pull requests that reference them**.

Further it explains what you can possibly do about it:

> You cannot remove sensitive data from other users' clones of your repository, but **you can permanently remove cached views and references to the sensitive data in pull requests on GitHub by contacting us through the GitHub Support portal. GitHub Support only assists in the removal of sensitive data in cases where we determine that the risk can't be mitigated by rotating affected credentials.**

My interpretation of that last sentence is GitHub's default is to decline the request, unless you can make a good case for why it's needed.

Comment: I guess the only way is to contact Github support